# move circle along with marker google maps javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a project in which i have marker on map with a circle around it. I want to move the circle along with marker. When ever i move the marker the circle remains to its last position. I want to move both that when ever i move the marker the circle should also move along with it.

Kindly tell me where i am doing mistake?

[image: When open page][image: When move marker circle is not moving with it.]

code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>      
<html>      
  <head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">      
    <meta charset="utf-8">      
    <title>Draw Circle on Marker Click on Google Map</title>      
    <style>      
      html, body {      
        height: 100%;      
        margin: 0;      
        padding: 0;      
      }      
      #map {      
        height: 99%;    
        width: 99%    
      }      
    </style>      
        <script async defer      
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>      
        <script>   

var markers = [];  
 var map;  
// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.      
var citymap = {lat:21.002471054356725, lng:79.12353515625};    

function initMap() {      
  var lat_lng = {lat: 22.08672, lng: 79.42444};       
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {      
    zoom: 6,      
    center: lat_lng,      
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN      
  });      

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({      
    position: lat_lng,   
      draggable:true ,  
    map: map  
  });    

   var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({      
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',      
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,      
      strokeWeight: 2,      
      fillColor: '#FF0000',      
      fillOpacity: 0.35,      
      map: map,      
      center: lat_lng,      
      radius: 199999.45454,    
      draggable:true    
    });  

}   


    </script>      
  </head>      
  <body>      
    <div id="map"></div>      
  </body>      
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to bind drag event with circle with `.addListener()` function

do it like this

```
function initMap() {      


var lat_lng = {lat: 22.08672, lng: 79.42444};       
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {      
    zoom: 6,      
    center: lat_lng,      
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN      
  });      

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({      
    position: lat_lng,   
      draggable:true ,  
    map: map  
  });    

   var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({      
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',      
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,      
      strokeWeight: 2,      
      fillColor: '#FF0000',      
      fillOpacity: 0.35,      
      map: map,      
      center: lat_lng,      
      radius: 199999.45454,    
      draggable:true    
    });  


   //add event listner on drag event of marker
    marker.addListener('drag', function(event) {                     
        cityCircle.setOptions({center:{lat:event.latLng.lat(),lng:event.latLng.lng()}});        
    });
}
```